# Counting subsets among not disjoint subsets

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Given $A$ a set of $n$ elements - note $|A|$ its cardinal and $P(A)$ its powerset. Let $A_1$, $A_2$... $A_k$, be $k$ subsets (not empty) of $A$.

$A_1$ generates $2^{|A_1|}$ different subsets of $A$ - meaning $|P(A_1)|=2^{|A_1|}$ and $P(A_1)\subset P(A)$
If $A_1$, $A_2$... $A_k$ are pairwise disjoint, they generate together $2^{|A_1|} + 2^{|A_2|}...2^{|A_k|}-k$ different non empty sets of $A$ . What if they are not disjoint ?

**How many different subsets of $A$ do $A_1$, $A_2$... $A_k$ generate together when they are not disjoint ?** - (is there a formula or a rapid algorithm to compute it ?) - In other words, what is the cardinal of $P(A_1)\cup P(A_2) \cup  ... \cup P(A_k)$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: Use the formula of exclusion-inclusion.

Comment: You are counting the empty set $k$ times.

Comment: @Wuestenfux Tks. How to compute it easily ?

Comment: @uniquesolution Tks, I modified the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "generate"?

Comment: @EricWofsey I modified the question to take into account your comment, tks.